# Creating a waveform which is abruptly changing from one frequency to another smoothly in LTspice

Tags: ltspice

I want to create a sine wave with offset which is abruptly changing from 1Hz to 10Hz at a desired point in time without discontinuity. I tried and could only reach the following result:

[image]

First of all, I had to use many sources and tweak them one by one. And most importantly in my circuit output there is a discontinuity. Below zookmed view of the plot shows that at around 400ms:

[image]

How can such wave form be achieved maybe a better way most importantly without that discontinuity?

Comment: You want an abrupt change but without a discontinuity yes? You think that spike is the only discontinuity yes?

Comment: Think about why you are adding the small fraction of time (0.40...01). You have selected a sine wave and frequency which starts and ends the signals at 0. If you sum them both you then get 0. Why are you then delaying the second signal instead of starting it at the end of the first sine?

Comment: Discontinuity might be the wrong term, I wanted to say the second wave should start from the end point of the first wave. I couldn't manage to do it.

Comment: @loudnoises Try to make this, you will see it is not that easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `MODULATOR` located in `SpecialFunctions/modulate.asy`:

[image]

`mark` and `space` sets your low and high frequency and are configured on the `SpiceLine` entry in the modulator, then change between them using the FM input. In this example I have a pulse changing from 0 to 1 volts every 2.5 seconds. Here is a zoom of one transition.

[image]

You can control the transition in any way you want, by using different PULSE or PWL commands. They will always be "glitch-free". You can change the amplitude using the AM input, which is 1 volt p-p by default.

Comment: Just so OP won't have to dig it up, the formula is `space + V(FM)*(mark - space)`.

Answer (score 1):

Never one to back down from a challenge, here is the solution I tried to guide you towards.

Period is defined by \$1/f\$, to ensure that a sine wave finishes at a zero-value the length must be a multiple of \$1/(2f)\$. This duration must be then added on to the second for the time delay.

I ran the 10 Hz sine wave for 4 periods which is a duration of \$4/10 = 0.4\$s, and so delayed the 100 Hz sine wave by 0.4s. Pictured below:

[image: Circuit to produce glitch-free transition]

(As an aside I found the DC offset of the voltage source to be unintuitive, it appears to be scaled by the inverse of the amplitude!)

This then produces a glitch-free transition:

[image: Glitch free sine wave transition]
[image: B-e-a-utiful]

As I was trying to suggest with my comment, you don't need to delay it by a fraction of a second, you need it to start at the exact moment the other stops. Please don't be so confrontational next time.

Having said this I would still probably opt for pipe's solution so that you don't have to add a new source every time you want to change frequency.